# Boolean quadratically constrained linear program (QCLP)

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, binary-programming, qclp

1) I have the following problem that I would like to first solve optimally but I have not been able to express it in a way that can be accepted by Matlab optimization functions.

$$\begin{array}{ll} 
\text{maximize} & {\bf c}^T{\bf x} \\ 
\text{subject to: } & {\bf A}_1{\bf x} = {\bf q} \\ 
& [{\bf B}_1 {\bf x}] \circ [{\bf B}_2 {\bf x}] = {\bf 0}\\ 
& [{\bf C}_1 {\bf x}] \circ [{\bf C}_2 {\bf x}] = {\bf 0}\\ 
& [{\bf D}_1 {\bf x}] \circ [{\bf D}_2 {\bf x}] = {\bf 0}\\ 
& x_i = \{0, 1\}
\end{array}$$

The symbol $\circ$ represents the Hadamard product. The elements of ${\bf c}$ are all non-negative. The elements of matrix ${\bf A}$ are all non-negative. The matrices ${\bf B}_1, {\bf B}_2, {\bf C}_1$ and ${\bf C}_2$ are sparse matrices with either $0 $ or $1$ as elements. Any idea about how to transform this system to be a valid input to any optimizer?

2) Then, I have decided to relax the constraints involving a Hadamard product by multiplying ${\bf 1}^T$ at each side of the equality (unweighted sum of constraints). Thus, I obtain

$$\begin{array}{ll} 
\text{maximize} & {\bf c}^T{\bf x} \\ 
\text{subject to: } & {\bf A}_1{\bf x} = {\bf q} \\ 
& {\bf x}^T {\bf A}_2 {\bf x} = 0 \\ 
& {\bf x}^T {\bf A}_3 {\bf x} = 0 \\ 
& {\bf x}^T {\bf A}_4 {\bf x} = 0 \\ 
& x_i = \{0, 1\}
\end{array}$$

where ${\bf A}_2, {\bf A}_3$ and ${\bf A}_4$ are also sparse matrices having $0$ or $1$ as their elements. Since these matrices are neither positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite, the relaxed problem is still non-convex (to the best of my knowledge). Can you please recommend a way to work this problem out a bit more? Is there any framework that allows me to further manipulate the problem and perhaps reach a simplified solution by hand?

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected it.

Comment: Instead of three equations using Hadamard products, you could have used $3n$ quadratic equations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rodrigo. I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

### Quadratic Forms

I believe these equations can be linearized by exploiting that $x$ are binary variables. Let's do the general equation $x^T A x= b$. This can be written as

$$ \sum_{i,j} x_i x_j a_{i,j} = b $$

Let's introduce a binary variable $y_{i,j} =  x_i x_j$. This product can be linearized as:

$$\begin{align}
  &y_{i,j} \le x_i\\
  &y_{i,j} \le x_j\\
  &y_{i,j} \ge x_i+x_j-1
\end{align}$$

So now we can write:

$$ \sum_{i,j} y_{i,j} a_{i,j} = b $$

This will now give you a linear MIP model, which you can solve with `intlinprog`.

Now for some bonus points. If we want to be frugal we can create and exploit some symmetry as follows:

$$\begin{align}
  &y_{i,j} \le x_i&&\forall i<j\\
  &y_{i,j} \le x_j&&\forall i<j\\
  &y_{i,j} \ge x_i+x_j-1&&\forall i<j\\
  &\sum_i x_i a_{i,i} + \sum_{i<j} y_{i,j} (a_{i,j}+a_{j,i}) = b 
\end{align}$$

This saves us a bunch of variables and equations.

### Hadamard Products

(Updated) Make them quadratic forms and see above.

Or if you adventurous, there is another formulation possible.
I am a bit less sure about this, but I think we have $(Ax) \circ (Bx) = 0$ or:

$$\begin{align}
 &u_i = \sum_j a_{i,j} x_j\\
 &v_i = \sum_j b_{i,j} x_j\\
 &u_i v_i = 0
\end{align}$$

Only the last equation is nonlinear. We can write this as $u_i=0 \text{ or } v_i=0$. Not so nice, but this can be linearized by:

$$\begin{align}
 &-M\delta_i \le u_i \le M \delta_i\\
 &-M(1-\delta_i) \le v_i \le M (1-\delta_i)\\
 &\delta_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$

where $M$ is a bound on $u,v$. We may be able to find good bounds by carefully looking at the matrices $A,B$ (or even by running a series of small optimization problems).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Erwin. I will go through your explanation and see if I can get your point.

Comment: Why treat the Hadamard products any differently? They are just quadratic equalities, so exactly the same linearization applies (except that you get $n$ quadratic equalities from every constraints)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Johan. Rodrigo has suggested the same. But now that I realize, the matrices that I have are quite large and decoupling each into more matrices makes it difficult to manage. Anyway, I am going to test this with small matrices and see how it goes.